# Use the DatePickers JQuery method on a CSS created image to populate input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

What I have done is created a a calendar image made purely of CSS. Now when the user clicks my calendar I would like the `datepicker` to pop up and allow the user to choose their date. When the date is chosen the day month and year values should be populated into three different input fields.

I have looked at many questions on Stack Overflow as well as other assets online and cannot find a way to do this. Some I have read say that by default it's bound to an input tag.

My current implementation is like this.

```
$(function() {
  $("#myDdate").datepicker({
      onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
          $('#year').val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
          $('#month').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
          $('#day').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
      }
  });
});
```

**Legend:**

`.mydate` = the `css` calendar image created
`#day`= an input field below the calendar css image for the day
`#month` = an input field below the calendar css image for the month
`#year` =  an input field below the calendar css  for the year

**Html that has `CSS` to look like a calendar:**

```
<div id=".myDate" class="icon">
   <em class="dayName"></em>
   <strong class="month"></strong>
   <span class="dayNumber"></span>
</div>
```

I got two of these calendars created. One for start date and end date. I know there must be a way to accomplish this, however I cannot find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("#myDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);

        $('#year').val(date.getFullYear());
        $('#month').val(date.getMonth());
        $('#day').val(date.getDate());
    }
});
```

**Explanation:**
`parseDate()` is a DatePicker's "utility function".
It creates a date object from the datePicker value.
Arguments are `parseDate(format, value, options)`. [Reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Then, on this date object, JavaScript Date methods can be used to manipulate it or extract parts. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp).

------
**EDIT**
Remove the dot in the element `id`, like below:

```
<div id="myDate" class="icon">
   <em class="dayName"></em>
   <strong class="month"></strong>
   <span class="dayNumber"></span>
</div>
```

In jQuery, a dot in front of a selector means a `class`.
To target an `id`, it's a `#`.

**Notice** the modification I just made on the jQuery selector.

------
**2nd EDIT**

«The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field.» [Reference](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

You tie it to a `div`... That's why it fails.
So if you don't want to see an input field... Here is a kind of hack:

```
<div id="myDate" class="icon">
   <em class="dayName"></em>
   <strong class="month"></strong>
   <span class="dayNumber"></span>
</div>
<input type="text" id="hiddenDatePicker" style="display:none;">
```

Script:

```
$("#myDate").on("click",function(){
    $("#hiddenDatePicker").css("display","inline");
    $("#hiddenDatePicker").focus();
});

$("#hiddenDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);

        $('#year').val(date.getFullYear());
        $('#month').val(date.getMonth());
        $('#day').val(date.getDate());
    },
    onClose: function(){
        $("#hiddenDatePicker").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

Comment: I will test as soon as I get to work. Could you please also add an explanation how it works? I do not fully understand why that would work over mine. Thanks.

Comment: Cannot seem to get it to work. I added the item that the datepicker is clicked on. (css calendar)

Comment: `<div id=".myDate" class="icon">` Remove the dot in the element `id`... And also change this : `$(".myDdate").datepicker({` to `$("#myDate").datepicker({`

Comment: Sorry that was an accident changing the variable name from mine to the one I am using in this post. Same result tho.

Comment: document.ready() just ensure the function is executed after the page has fully loaded. If you script is at the bottom of the page and the target `div` is not dynamically created, it's not that usefull...

Comment: So my javacsript page links are at th ebottom of the page before the closing body tag. Then in the js file i have document ready with your method inside. And of course the css to make that div and 3 elements look lik a calendar.

Comment: If you think people could benefit from my post please mark the post up :)